# Add Rasters to Mosaic Dataset eliminates bands using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, multi-band, mosaic-dataset, maxar-digitalglobe, worldview-2

I am trying to create a mosaic dataset that can have any MAXAR imagery added to it (i.e. 4 band GeoEye or 8 band WorldView-2). In order to do so, I have created a Mosaic Dataset without specifying the Product Definition in Create Mosaic Dataset, but then specify WorldView-2 in Add Rasters to Mosaic Dataset via raster_type. When I do this, my mosaic dataset is cut to only have 4 bands (which are not defined in Source Band information in the Mosaic Dataset's properties). The bands are also re-ordered oddly with the red band as 1.

Conversely, when I specify WorldView-2 in the Product Definition when initially creating the mosaic dataset, and then add the imagery, I do not lose any bands and the band metadata carries over.

How can I create a mosaic dataset without defining the sensor (so that I can have imagery from various sensors) without losing bands?